# Создание динамического пути app url

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите как можно создать динамический подстановки url
ссылка на картинку

```
img src="{{ Storage::url($citizen->photo) }}"
```

А это сам адрес его нужно сделать динамическим

```
APP_URL=http://192.168.91.130
```

При перемещении моего проекта на новый сервер не грузятся пути к картинке и мне необходимо в файл .env подставлять новый ip. Как сделать его динамическим чтобы не приходилось заново вписывать новый ip?

Comment: Что подразумевается под "динамическим" путём к картинке? И в чём, собственно, проблема? Непонятно что хотите сделать

Comment: Под динамическим подразумевается что если адрес сервера будет другим то не приходилось идти в файл .env и настраивать путь

Comment: В общем, чтобы путь к картинке не зависел от адреса сервера.

Comment: вообще для этого и сделан файл .env от которого всё приложение и строится. И у каждого разработчика свой .env файл. У меня будет localhost:3000 у вас http://192.168.91.130 а на бою мой-сайт.ru и всё будет работать как надо. env не передается на сервер при каждом обновлении приложения. А всегда 1 для каждой машины где развёрнуто приложение

Comment: а вообще это можно сделать динамически?

Comment: ну все библиотеки и ядро ларавель будет строиться от APP_URL, все Storage, File и т.д.. можете сделать свой кастомный диск https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#custom-filesystems  или сделать кастомных хост в конфиге для получения пути к файлам как хотите https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#url-host-customization как раз это поможет получать урл какой хотите не меняя app_url

Comment: а можно сделать сам APP_URL динамическим, чтобы он получал данные по конкретному ip?

Comment: можно ли подставить значение $_server 'http_host' в APP_URL?

Comment: Он вообщето его в конфиг ложит, там можете вызвать функцию или взять из сервера чего не рекомендую